# Proper approach how to add context from external source to records in Kafka Streams

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have records that are processed with Kafka Streams (using Processor API). Let's say the record has `city_id` and some other fields.

In Kafka Streams app I want to add current temperature in the target city to the record.
`Temperature<->City` pairs are stored in eg. Postgres.

In Java application I'm able to connect to Postgres using JDBC and build `new HashMap<CityId, Temperature>` so I'm able to lookup temperature based on `city_id`. Something like `tempHM.get(record.city_id)`.

There are several questions how to best approach it:

### Where to initiate the context data?

Originally, I have been doing it within `AbstractProcessor::init()` but that seems wrong as it's initialized for each thread and also reinitialized on rebalance.

So I moved it before streams topology builder and processors are build with it. Data are fetched only once independently on all processor instances.

Is that proper and valid approach. It works but...

```java
HashMap<CityId, Temperature> tempHM = new HashMap<CityId, Temperature>;

// Connect to DB and initialize tempHM here

Topology topology = new Topology();

topology
    .addSource(SOURCE, stringDerializer, protoDeserializer, "topic-in")

    .addProcessor(TemperatureAppender.NAME, () -> new TemperatureAppender(tempHm), SOURCE)

    .addSink(SINK, "topic-out", stringSerializer, protoSerializer, TemperatureAppender.NAME)
;
```

### How to refresh the context data?

I would like to refresh the temperature data every 15 minutes for example. I was thinking of using Hashmap container instead of Hashmap, that would handle it:

```java
abstract class ContextContainer<T> {

    T context;
    Date lastRefreshAt;

    ContextContainer(Date now) {
        refresh(now);
    }

    abstract void refresh(Date now);

    abstract Duration getRefreshInterval();

    T get() {
        return context;
    }

    boolean isDueToRefresh(Date now) {
        return lastRefreshAt == null
            || lastRefreshAt.getTime() + getRefreshInterval().toMillis() < now.getTime();
    }
}

final class CityTemperatureContextContainer extends ContextContainer<HashMap> {

    CityTemperatureContextContainer(Date now) {
        super(now);
    }

    void refresh(Date now) {
        if (!isDueToRefresh(now)) {
            return;
        }

        HashMap context = new HashMap();
        // Connect to DB and get data and fill hashmap

        lastRefreshAt = now;
        this.context = context;
    }

    Duration getRefreshInterval() {
        return Duration.ofMinutes(15);
    }
}
```

*this is a brief concept written in SO textarea, might contain some syntax errors but the point is clear I hope*

then passing it into processor like `.addProcessor(TemperatureAppender.NAME, () -> new TemperatureAppender(cityTemperatureContextContainer), SOURCE)`

And in processor do

```java
    public void init(final ProcessorContext context) {
        context.schedule(
            Duration.ofMinutes(1),
            PunctuationType.STREAM_TIME,
            (timestamp) -> { 
                cityTemperatureContextContainer.refresh(new Date(timestamp));
                tempHm = cityTemperatureContextContainer.get();
            }    
        );

        super.init(context);
    }
```

Is there a better way? The main question is about finding proper concept, I'm able to implement it then. There is not much resources on the topic out there though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In Kafka Streams app I want to add current temperature in the target city to the record. `Temperature<->City` pairs are stored in eg. Postgres.
>
> In Java application I'm able to connect to Postgres using JDBC and build new `HashMap<CityId, Temperature>` so I'm able to lookup temperature based on `city_id`. Something like `tempHM.get(record.city_id)`.

A better alternative would be to use Kafka Connect to ingest your data from Postgres into a Kafka topic, read this topic into a `KTable` in your application with Kafka Streams, and then join this `KTable` with your other stream (the stream of records "with `city_id` and some other fields"). That is, you will be doing a `KStream`-to-`KTable` join.

Think:

```
### Architecture view

DB (here: Postgres) --Kafka Connect--> Kafka --> Kafka Streams Application


### Data view

Postgres Table ----------------------> Topic --> KTable
```

Example connectors for your use case are https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc and https://www.confluent.io/hub/debezium/debezium-connector-postgresql.

One of the advantages of the Kafka Connect based setup above is that you no longer need to talk directly from your Java application (which uses Kafka Streams) to your Postgres DB.

Another advantage is that you don't need to do "batch refreshes" of your context data (you mentioned every 15 minutes) from your DB into your Java application, because the application would get the latest DB changes in real-time automatically via the DB->KConnect->Kafka->KStreams-app flow.

Comment: So the point here is to get my context data to a topic and then join data from the topic within stream app as KTable/Stream. In this case KTable seems more appropriate. And I can use KConnect to populate the topic with data if applicable (eg. for db supporting JDBC). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Example connectors for your use case are https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc and https://www.confluent.io/hub/debezium/debezium-connector-postgresql.